# SVN client for SQL Server Management Studio 2005

Tags: sql, svn, ssms, svn-client

I have installed Tortoise SVN and AnkhSVN, but neither one shows up in my SQL Server Management Studio 2005 under the Source Code Control options.

I know they work because all my Visual Studio projects are working fine.

Do I have to do install a different SVN client to integrate to SQL Server Management Studio?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no SVN integration for SSMS from either TortoiseSVN or AnkhSVN. The only viable option is to use [RedGate SQL Source Control](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Source_Control/). Or create a Database project in Visual Studio and keep all the scripts and structure in there, forcing all the developers modify those files first.

Personally, I use [ScriptDB](http://scriptdb.codeplex.com/) and run it on an hourly basis with svn auto-commit of changes made to the database so that I can keep track of what's changing.

Answer (score 6):

I use *Agent SVN* which is a MS-SCCI plug-in and it works fine with SSMS.

http://www.zeusedit.com/agent/ssms/ms_ssms.html

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at Red Gate's SQL Server Managemnt Studio SVN client?

http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Source_Control/